# Google maps zoom level

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm displaying current location in map using that code:

```
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    public static Location mLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_maps);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new   GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                mLocation = location;
                displayCurrentLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    public  void displayCurrentLocation() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
                target(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude())).
                zoom(15).
                bearing(0).
                build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

If I'll zoom in after few second zoom level returns to it's starter position. I know it's because of zoom(15) in my listener but is there any possibility to don't do that? If use will zoom in and will start walking I don't want to lose my zoom level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a String data member in class

```
String loadLocation="notDone"
```

in onMyLocationChange

```
 mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            mLocation = location;
            if(loadLocation.equals("notDone")){
                displayCurrentLocation();
            }
        }
    });
```

in displayCurrentLocation method

```
  public  void displayCurrentLocation(){
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
            target(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude())).
            tilt(60).
            zoom(15).
            bearing(0).
            build();
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        loadLocation="done";
}
```

now this method displayCurrentLocation() call only 1 time, when map screen will open.
try this.

Comment: variable loadLocation is accessed from within inner class. it needs to be final.

Comment: not final, If you be it final then you can not change its value, its value can change only in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public  void displayCurrentLocation() {
float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
                target(new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude())).
                zoom(zoom ).
                bearing(0).
                build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```